# Log of computer uptime and main CPU consuming threads

Tags: windows-7, cpu, logging, uptime

Is it possible, with a built-in Windows 7 tool, to get something like this for the past 3 months :

```
DATE        COMPUTER ON TIME  COMPUTER OFF TIME     DURATION   MAIN CPU-CONSUMING PROCESSES 
2016-06-30  10:00             (currently running)   -          Firefox (4%), Blabla (2%), ...
2016-06-29  18:04             22:25                 4:21       blabla (7%), dqsdsqd (2%), ...
2016-06-29  10:12             13:26                 3:14       hacktool (20%), ....
...
```

If no built-in way, is there a freeware for this?

*Note: This could be used, among other reasons, as a way to identify malware that consume CPU.  I noticed yesterday that a `.exe` was using 20% of CPU constantly! The computer was constatntly hot and fan in high speed the last 2 months, so this 20% consuming-CPU malware/hacktool could be the reason!*

Comment: What was the .exe

Comment: `mfutil.exe` which is [said to be part of Avast](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=158819.0), but some other sources say it may be hacked as a hacktool. That's why a log of activity of past months would help me to understand what happened... Such a logging tool will also be useful in the future.

Comment: The answer to your question is no. You can create a tool that logs this, and then read back the log files it creates limiting it to the last 2 months. Some of the requested data can be retrieved, but most cannot.